# JavaScript Boolean to check if Google Auth token is still valid?

Tags: javascript, token, google-authentication

So if a user first visits the page and still hasnt authorized information share is there a way to detect if there is even a token or if the token is still valid using JavaScipt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out:

```
google.accounts.user.checkLogin(scope)
```